# algebraic proof of Hodge decomposition theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a proof for the Hodge decomposition for nonsingular projective algebraic varieties using only algebraic geometry without the language of Kähler manifolds and techniques from analysis etc. If there is one where can I find it?

Comment: Did you see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28265/proving-hodge-decomposition-without-using-the-theory-of-elliptic-operators ?

Answer (score 4):

Deligne and Illusie proved the degeneration of Hodge to de Rahm (see e.g. http://math.bu.edu/people/potthars/writings/HdRSS.pdf for a brief review):

> Relevements modulo $p^2$ et
>   decomposition du complexe de De Rham,
>   Inv. Math. **89** (1987), 247-270.

BUT the Deligne-Illusie approach does only says that the spectral suequence degenerates at $E_1$ (with $E_1$ terms being $H^q(X,\Omega^p_X)$). But is does not give an explicit isomorphism between $H^n(X)$ and $\oplus_{p+q=n}H^q(X,\Omega^p_X)$.

I heard about a work-in-progress by Dima Arinkin, Andrei Caldararu and Marton Hablicsek, where they have a new approach to Deligne-Illusie *via* derived geometry. It might be that there approach gives the Hodge decomposition (I actualy don't know if this is the case or not).

Comment: I think in char.p it is not possible to get a decomposition, even if you have a lifting. The decomposition is highly transcendental in some sense, since it uses complex conjugation. And it follows from the existence of a Kahler metric. As Mumford suggested in his pathologies paper, projective in char.p is not as strong as a Kahler metric over the complex numbers.

Comment: The Hodge filtration exists algebraically in families, namely, there is a filtration of the algebraic vector bundle by algebraic subbundles which gives the Hodge filtration at each point. This is not true for the Hodge decomposition, which makes it unlikely that there is an algebraic construction of the decomposition. My impression is that the ACH approach says nothing about this.