# Does uniformization require choice?

Tags: riemann-surfaces

On Twitter, Ricardo Pérez Marco recently [asserted](https://twitter.com/rperezmarco/status/1088022578311192576) that all known proofs of the Poincaré-Koebe uniformization theorem rely on the Axiom of Choice. Is this true?

Comment: As far I can remember, the standard proof relies on some PDE techniques (existence of the solution for some Dirichlet problem, existence of a Green function). Do the proofs of these result use some form of the Hahn-Banach theorem somewhere?

Comment: Finding explicit maps that uniformize (if that is the word) even fairly simple shaped simply connected domains is incredibly difficult.  So isn't this just the sort of problem that is bound to require the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: Well,  for example maps may well given by power series which you can compute by some complicated recursion. It would be very surprising if this fact really required choice.

Comment: Suppose that when I constructed my simply connected domain I made countably many arbitrary choices.  I don't see how you can compute a uniformizing function for my domain in general.  To be more explicit, I'm going to take as my domain the union of the lower half plane and discs of radius $1/3$ centered at some elements of $\mathbb{Z}$.  I'm thinking of the case when my subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is not recursively enumerable.  Surely you will need at least Choice for countable sets.

Comment: You might be interested in this question as well: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158779/reverse-mathematics-of-meromorphic-functions-on-riemann-surfaces/181820#181820