# Is there a proof of Hodge theory using condensed mathematics?

Tags: complex-geometry, hodge-theory, condensed-mathematics

As is well known, many results in complex geometry "feel" algebraic (and often have statements which are "completely algebraic") but only have "transcendental" proofs (i.e., using analysis in some essential way). One of the promises of the newly-developed condensed mathematics is to put (almost?) all of the analysis needed in one black-box (the fact that the category of liquid vector spaces is abelian). This should allow for new proofs of the classical results which "feel" more algebraic.

In [this recent course](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/Complex.pdf), Clausen and Scholze prove quite a lot of interesting results in this fashion. One essential omission is some form of the Hodge decomposition, whose usual proof relies on a very hard theorem on elliptic differential operators. **I wonder, then, if it's reasonable to expect condensed mathematics to be able to prove something like the Hodge decomposition.**

I'm pretty sure that, as of today, there's no published proof of this. So, my hopes are to receive answers on the lines of "*this* is an essential problem which seems very hard to solve" or "I've talked with [insert a collection of people], and they seem to have a proof in their minds". Perhaps even "oh, but this is a very simple corollary of [insert reference]". (I would be surprised, though...)

Comment: It might be better to formulate the decomposition theorem, to make clear what we start with (a complex smooth projective variety or a complex manifold with some conditions), and the precise conclusion (e.g. simply the existence of a splitting, or induced by something). An example is Deligne–Illusie's proof, which is algebraic but the conclusion [seems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28265/proving-hodge-decomposition-without-using-the-theory-of-elliptic-operators#comment61220_28269) to be weaker than the decomposition theorem that complex geometers refer to.

Comment: Perfect question! This is a problem that's very much on our minds, but where we feel that we do not yet have the correct approach. (In p-adic Hodge theory, the Fargues-Fontaine curve plays a central role, and similarly in complex Hodge theory it seems that the twistor-$\mathbb P^1$ plays an important role (work of Simpson, Mochizuki, ...), and ideally we'd like to develop Hodge theory in a way that makes the twistor-$\mathbb P^1$ appear organically. But we don't yet see how.)

Comment: Dear @PeterScholze, if you could expand this a little into an answer, I would be glad to accept it!

Comment: @Z.M I was imprecise on purpose! I would be happy to learn about any progress whatsoever on this direction :)